# How can I solve a 2nd order ODE containing an integral with NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, special-functions, integral-equations

I'm trying to solve a equation of gravitional wave propagation given by

$$
\chi''(u) + \frac{2}{u} \chi'(u) + \chi(u) = -\frac{24 f_h (u)}{u^2}\int^u_0  \frac{j_2 (u - U)}{(u - U)^2}\chi'(U)\mathrm dU,
$$

with initial conditions

$$
\chi(0) = 1, \qquad \chi'(0) = 0
$$

$ f_h(u) $ can be taken as constant for simplicity. $ j_2(x) $ is the 2nd order Spherical Bessel function.

However, the `NDSolve` expression I used always has some problem:

```
fneutrino[x_] := 0.40523

NDSolve[{y''[x] + 2 y'[x]/x + y[x] == 24 fneutrino[x]/x^2*
Integrate[SphericalBesselJ[2, x - a]/(x - a)^2*y'[a], {a, 0, x}], 
y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 3}, 
Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"}]
```

[image]

Can someone help? Thanks very much in ahead.

Comment: You might want to make sure the integration is not causing problem, by doing: 

  `int[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[SphericalBesselJ[2, x - a]/(x - a)^2, {a, 0., x}]` then `NDSolve[{y''[x] + 2 y'[x]/x + y[x] == 24 fneutrino[x]/x^2*int[x], 
    y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 3}]`.

Now you get other errors due to division by $0$...

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Now the problem more or less is solved. I can redefine the initial condition to be not 0.

Comment: Are you changing the initial condition would suffice? It does not seem like it. It looks like your ODE is singular but I'm not sure.

Comment: I think the initial condition is not the problem. But I still have a problem which is the integration should include the first derivative y'[a]. I can't define it first and do the NDSolve like you.

Comment: This is not a PDE

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; Remove["Global`*"];

fneutrino[x_] := 40523/100000;

SOL = FixedPointList[Function[y, Module[{int, y1, eps},
eps = 10^-5;
int[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[SphericalBesselJ[2, x - t]/(x - t)^2*y'[t], {t, 0, x}, 
Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0},MaxRecursion -> 50]; 
NDSolve[{y1''[x] + 2/(x + eps)*y1'[x] + y1[x] + (24*fneutrino[x])/(x^2 + eps)*int[x] == 0, 
y1[0] == 1, y1'[0] == 0}, y1, {x, 0, 10}, Method -> "Adams", 
PrecisionGoal -> 20]][[1, 1, 2]]], Function[x, x], 
SameTest -> (Max[Abs[Table[#1[x] - #2[x], {x, 0, 10, 1/20}]]] < 10^-5 &)];

Plot[{Evaluate[SOL[[-1]][x]], Evaluate[D[SOL[[-1]][x], x]]}, {x, 0, 
10}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Blue}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> {"y[x]", "y'[x]"}]
```

[image]

Numeric **errors** check:

```
Y[x_] := (SOL[[-1]][x]);
CHECK[x_?NumericQ] := Y''[x] + 2/x*Y'[x] + Y[x] + (24*fneutrino[x])/x^2*
NIntegrate[SphericalBesselJ[2, x - t]/(x - t)^2*Y'[t], {t, 0, x}, 
Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]

Plot[CHECK[x], {x, 5*10^-1, 10}, PlotRange ->All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
        By adding a small number  you can avoid singular point within your  presion.  Your plot looks liks below?
          sol = NDSolve[{y''[x] + 2 y'[x]/(x + 10^-10) + y[x] == 
         24 fneutrino[x]/(x^2 + 10^-10)*int[x], y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, 
         y, {x, 0, 3}]
          DiscretePlot[(y[x] /. sol), {x, 0, 3, .001}, Frame -> True, 
           ImageSize -> 550, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotRange -> All]


          [![plot of your PDE][1]][1]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps solve the initial singular problem. But I still have a problem which is the integration should include the first derivative y'[a]. I can't define it first and do the NDSolve like anderstood did.